# Reference for relation between class number of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-p}]$ and partial quotients of $\sqrt p$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, complex-geometry, continued-fractions

So in Ireland and Rosen's, "Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory", they mention the following incredible fact at the end of Chapter 13, section 1. Suppose $p \neq 3$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{p}]$ has class number one. Let $\sqrt{p}=[a_{0}, \overline{a_1 ,\ldots a_{n}}]$ be its continued fraction expansion. Then $\frac{1}{3}(a_n - a_{n-1} + \ldots \pm a_1)$ is the class number of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-p}]$. The fact is attributed to Hirzebruch, and I have no clue how it is proven, and am unable to find a proof. Talking to a professor and a little research revealed that this has something to do with the Hilbert modular surface. I would appreciate some help in understanding this incredible fact!

Comment: Very interesting！

Comment: See also Zagier''s book "Quadratische Zahlkörper".

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting indeed!

This is explained in

> Hirzebruch, F., 
>    *Hilbert modular surfaces and class numbers.* 
>   Colloque “Analyse et Topologie” en l’Honneur de Henri Cartan (Orsay, 1974), pp. 151–164.
>   Asterisque, No. 32-33, Soc. Math.France, Paris, 1976.

From the Math.Sci.Net review:

> This is a survey, largely without proofs, of recent work of the author, done partly in collaboration
>   with D. B. Zagier, on the geometry of the Hilbert modular surface(s) associated to a real quadratic
>   ﬁeld, concentrating particularly on the appearance therein of class numbers.

... and later in the review ...

> He then introduces the Hilbert modular surfaces: the compactiﬁed and resolved quotients of the
>   actions of congruence subgroups of SL2 over the integers of the real quadratic ﬁeld, acting on H ×
>   H. He sketches the results [op. cit.] about the signature of the quotient and how, as a consequence
>   of all of the foregoing considerations, one is able to express, for a prime p of form 4m − 1, p > 3,
>   the class number of the quadratic ﬁeld of discriminant −p in terms of the period of the continued
>   fraction for $p^{1/2}$ whenever the class number of the quadratic ﬁeld of discriminant 4p is one.

Comment: Thanks! It appears to be here but is not accesible. http://hirzebruch.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/143/

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a reference! Thank you to Jared Weinstein for supplying the reference and Jeremy Booher for the excellent exposition.

http://math.stanford.edu/~jbooher/expos/hilbert_modular_surfaces.pdf